# What does the Kaladesh Remastered (KLR) symbol represent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Please advise: what does the set symbol for Kaladesh Remastered (KLR) represent?

https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Kaladesh_Remastered

https://scryfall.com/sets/klr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [fandom](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Kaladesh#Set_details), the expansion symbol is a:

> Far Eastern inspired floral motif, representing the aether of the
> plane.

Comment: I will stick with "Swirling aether" for MTG Studio.

Comment: I just realized that the page I linked was for Kaladesh not Kaladesh Remastered, but the symbols are extremely similar so I'm assuming that my answer is still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The *Kaladesh Remastered* set symbol is an aesthetic merger of the *Kaladesh* and *Aether Revolt* set symbols. It is primarily based on the *Kaladesh* symbol, with some added motifs from the *Aether Revolt* symbol at the top (at the “spout”) and bottom (pointy!).

I've arranged them here in a line with *Kaladesh Remastered* in the middle:

[image: Kaladesh]
[image: Kaladesh Remastered]
[image: Aether Revolt]
<sub>*Left: Kaladesh, middle: Kaladesh Remastered, right: Aether Revolt. Source: [Keyrune](https://keyrune.andrewgioia.com/)*</sub>

This is similar to how *Amonkhet Remastered*'s set symbol merged those of AKH and HOU, by superimposing the latter over the former.

To the extent it depicts anything, let's go through the component symbols.

- The *Kaladesh* set symbol depicts a portion of the Consulate symbol, prominently featured in [Authority of the Consuls](https://scryfall.com/card/kld/5/authority-of-the-consuls) and [Greenwheel Liberator](https://scryfall.com/card/aer/108/greenwheel-liberator). Their symbol represents an aether reservoir holding aether, seen in [Aetherflux Reservoir](https://scryfall.com/card/klr/217/aetherflux-reservoir).
- The *Aether Revolt* symbol *apparently* depicts leaking aether? Presumably it's got something to do with the Renegade symbol, prominently featured in [Call for Unity](https://scryfall.com/card/aer/9/call-for-unity), which depicts an aether reservoir shattered and leaking. It's a pretty plain statement of their mission: overturn the Consulate, which extracts, regulates, and distributes aether, and return it to the people.

So between these, it mostly depicts the reservoir still, but it's spilling over at the top? Maybe it's a spilling or leaking aether reservoir. But I'm not certain it is, in fact, made to depict something, so much as it's meant to just unite the two set symbols.